# php/SQL function not working? trying to get the membership_id from a database

Tags: php, sql

```
    function get_user_id() 
    {
        global $db;

        $userid = NULL;

        if (!empty($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'])) 
        {
            $result = $db->execute("
                SELECT profile_id 
                FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "profile_online 
                WHERE hash = '" . $db->escape_string($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']) . "'
            ");

            if ($row = $db->fetch_array($result)) 
            {
                $userid = $row[0];
            }
        }

        return $userid;
    }

function get_membership_id($userid) 
    {
        global $db;

        $result = $db->execute("
        SELECT * FROM date_profile WHERE profile_id = '" . $db->escape_string($userid) . "'");

        $mem = $db->fetch_array($result)
        $membership = $mem[17];


        return $membership;
    }
```

the `get_user_id` is functioning fine...  but the membership part i just can't get it to work..

I am trying to take the membership ids.. and make it so certain code will not run for them.

with an :  `if ($membership != 18 )`
so it shows all everyone except the membership 18 people...

also tried this:

```
function get_membership_id($userid) 
{
  global $db;

  $membership = $db->execute("SELECT `membership_type_id` FROM `date_profile` WHERE `profile_id`= '" . $db->escape_string($userid) . "'");


  return $membership;
}
```

any help would be appreciated greatly.

Comment: You should turn on error reporting so you can debug yourself in future. It's very useful to learn how to find the issues so you can learn how to fix them.

Answer (score 4):

missed `;` here

```
$mem = $db->fetch_array($result);
                                ^
```

Comment: added.. fixed nothing..  it did not even register as an error without it.. how odd

Answer (score 1):

You're missing semicolon after `$mem = $db->fetch_array($result)`.

Comment: added ... did not.. it did not even read as an error..  very odd.

Answer (score 0):

forgot to use TABLE_PREFIX constant.

`SELECT * FROM  " . TABLE_PREFIX . "date_profile WHERE profile_id ...`

Comment: Table Prefix is for something else.. I did not forget it